# ContourPlot: Different Colouring for Closed and Open Contours

Tags: plotting

I make a contour plot of a function as follows:

```
s = ContourPlot[(1/2) u^(2) + 1 - Cos[Theta], {Theta, -4 Pi, 4 Pi}, {u, -5, 5}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> "Contours of E"]
```

and I have to:

1) no shading between contours (I use `ContourShadings ->None`)
2) Closed contours are blue
3) Open contours are red
4) The contour dividing the regions of closed contours and open contours is a thick black line.

Anyone can help with 2) and 3)? I suppose at 4) I use `ContourStyle-> {Thick,Black}`?

Thanks

Comment: The thin black line around the thick black one is the one that indicates the end of the closed contours? Normally the closed contours are from -2 to 2 but here it is from -2.07 to 2.07.

Comment: They should be at 2, as you suggest.

Comment: I would gladly do, but it says i need 15 reputation to display my upvotes.

Comment: Indeed I found your answer most helpful, since it illuminated me, but again "thanks for the feedback! Once you earn a total of 15 reputaion, your votes will change the publicly displayed post score".

Comment: I am not sure that your comments, which appear to be meant for march, are reaching him.  Unless your comments are attached to an answer that he authored, you need to include @march in the your comments to him.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I went back and forth on that comment, and I always forgot about the upvote rep limit. Also, I first wrote that thinking that you'd accepted the other answer, and I figured it should get the upvote along with the accept (because in the end it doesn't really matter except for the future users with questions). Anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This solves your *specific* problem. It does not generalize in the sense that you need to know the values of the contours beforehand and also know which ones correspond to closed and open. Anyway

```
vals = {0.5, 1, 2, 5, 6.5, 8, 10};
s = ContourPlot[(1/2) u^(2) + 1 - Cos[Theta]
  , {Theta, -4 Pi, 4 Pi}, {u, -5, 5}
  , ContourShading -> None
  , Contours -> {0.5, 1, 2, 5, 6.5, 8, 10}
  , ContourStyle -> Map[Which[# < 2, Blue, # == 2, {Black, Thick}, # > 2, Red] &, vals]
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Based on the now-deleted answer by [belisarius is forth](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/193/belisarius-is-forth), I suggest

```
ContourPlot[(1/2) u^(2) + 1 - Cos[Theta], {Theta, -4 Pi, 4 Pi}, {u, -5, 5}, 
    PlotLegends -> LineLegend[{Blue, Black, Red}, {"Closed", "Separatrix", "Open"}], 
    PlotLabel -> "Contours of E", ContourShading -> False, Contours -> Range[0, 15, .5], 
    ContourStyle -> Join[ConstantArray[Blue, 4], {{Thick, Black}}, ConstantArray[Red, 30]]]
```

[image]

Comment: @BrettChampion  Thanks for correcting my careless use of `PlotLegends`.

Answer (score 0):

When we don't know the levels corresponding to the open and closed contour lines, we can identify the closed contour lines exploiting the fact that for closed lines the first and last points are the same. Of course, there is no such convenient trick to identify a "Separatrix".

```
cp = ContourPlot[(1/2) u^(2) + 1 - Cos[Theta], {Theta, -4 Pi, 4 Pi}, {u, -5, 5}, 
 ContourShading -> None, Contours -> {Automatic, 30}, ImageSize -> 300, PlotPoints ->200];

lines = Cases[Normal[cp], Line[x_], Infinity];
difs = Norm[#[[1, -1]] - #[[1, 1]]] & /@ lines;
closed = Pick[lines, difs, 0.];
open = Complement[lines, closed];
Row[{cp, Graphics[{Blue, closed, Red, open},
 AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 300, Frame -> True]}]
```

[image]

With

```
options = {ContourShading -> None, Contours -> {Automatic, 10}, ImageSize -> 300, 
  PlotPoints -> 200};
cp = ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}, Evaluate[options]];
```

the same procedure gives

[image]

And, with

```
cp = ContourPlot[Evaluate[Sum[Sin[RandomReal[5, 2].{x, y}], {5}]], 
 {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}, Evaluate[options]];
```

[image]