# Trajectories of system of parametric equations

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions

I have to obtain plots of trajectories for (theta(t),u(t)) and then overlay them with a contour plot. The overlaying with the contour plot it is easy. What trubles me though is the trajectory part.

First, I solve the system, then I do a simple plot for the values and finally a parametric plot as follows:

```
s = NDSolve[{Theta'[t] == u[t], u'[t] == -Sin[Theta[t]], 
Theta[0] == 0, u[0] == 1.5}, {Theta, u}, {t, -4 Pi, 4 Pi}]

Plot[Evaluate[{Theta[t], u[t]} /. s], {t, -4 Pi, 4 Pi}, 
PlotLegends -> {"Theta[t]", "u[t]"}, AxesLabel -> {t, E[t]}, 
LabelStyle -> Directive[Blue, Bold]]

ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{Theta[t], u[t]} /. s], {t, -4 Pi, 4 Pi}]

Show[ContourPlot[(1/2) u^(2) + 1 - Cos[Theta], {Theta, -4 Pi, 
4 Pi}, {u, -5, 5}], 
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{Theta[t], u[t]} /. s], {t, -4 Pi, 4 Pi}]]
```

After getting the the parametric plot, using Show[...] I combine it with the contour one. Instead of recurring at every closed contour, it appears only once.

Do I have to use a different kind of plotting to have it repeatedly?

Comment: I don't see a `ContourPlot` in your code. Where is the contour plot? And what do you mean by "Instead of recurring at every closed contour, it appears only once."?

Comment: I used this:   
    Show[ContourPlot[(1/2) u^(2) + 1 - Cos[Theta], {Theta, -4 Pi, 
    4 Pi}, {u, -5, 5}], 
    ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{Theta[t], u[t]} /. s], {t, -4 Pi, 4 Pi}]]

to combine the contour plot and the parametric above, and when I do the parametric appears inside a closed contour only once. Should it appear more times, since it states "trajectory" shouldn't it repeat? @march

Comment: For the un-damped, non-driven pendulum, the contours of constant energy are exactly the trajectories in phase space. For this reason, you could just use the solution from [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/96642/29734). Your different trajectories (the different closed-curve ellipses) all represent the same trajectory, actually, since really, $-\pi/2\leq\theta \leq \pi/2$, so you really only need to plot in this region.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s = ParametricNDSolveValue[{th'[t] == u[t], u'[t] == -Sin[th[t]], 
                            th[0] == i, u[0] == 1.5}, {th, u}, {t, -4 Pi, 4 Pi}, {i}]
Show[
     ContourPlot[(1/2) u^(2) + 1 - Cos[th], {th, -4 Pi, 4 Pi}, {u, -5, 5}, 
                ColorFunction -> "Pastel"], 
     ParametricPlot[Through[s[#][t]], {t, -4 Pi, 4 Pi}] & /@ Pi Range[-4, 4, 2]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks again :) answer exactly on point!

Comment: I am having a problem with the `ParametricPlot` portion. I'm on 10.2 and started a new Mathematica and copied and executed your code. The `ParametricPlot` has a problem. I ran a test replacing `ParametricPlot` with  `Table`. This `Table[Through[s[#][t]], {t, -4 Pi, 4 Pi}] & /@ Pi Range[-4, 4, 2]` produces `{-4 \[Pi], -2 \[Pi], 0, 2 \[Pi], 4 \[Pi]}`. However when I write it out a bit more `Map[
 (Table[Through[s[#][t]], {t, -4 \[Pi], 4 \[Pi]}]) &,
 Pi Range[-4, 4, 2]
 ]` I get the right answer. I am a bit lost.

Comment: This works `Show[
 ContourPlot[(1/2) u^(2) + 1 - Cos[th], {th, -4 Pi, 4 Pi}, {u, -5, 5},
   ColorFunction -> "Pastel"],
 Map[
  (ParametricPlot[Through[s[#][t]], {t, -4 \[Pi], 4 \[Pi]}]) &,
  Pi Range[-4, 4, 2]
  ]
 ]`